# const input vs non-const output

Tags: c++

I have a function which traverses a tree of objects and does not modify any of the objects in the tree.

The function looks something like this:

```
static Node* findMatchingNode(const Node& root, const SomeFilterData& d);

struct Node {
   Node* left;
   Node* right;
};
```

The function can return the root or any object in the tree or nothing. It's obvious than with given declaration I have to perform *const_cast* somewhere, which is forbidden in most cases.

Is it acceptable for a function to guarantee constness and at the same time allow anyone to modify its output?

***EDIT**. I haven't stated this clearly, my function really does not modify any of the nodes in the tree, doesn't create new Node, it's pure function. I'd like to always have `const` qualifier there to tell everyone clearly that the function doesn't modify anything*

***EDIT**. The unspoken problem behind is that there is no legal way to express constness of the input during the function execution (and only inside the function) without enforcing the output constness.*

Comment: why is so obvious "that with given declaration I have to perform const_cast somewhere"?

Comment: @dlavila: Because he returns a non-const result.

Comment: I have had this problem before but was afraid to ask for help. +1

Comment: The C++ Standard Library has a related issue: modifying a data structure at a certain position specified by an iterator. Here, since the modification requires a non-const access to the data structure, a const iterator argument is sufficient. For example: [`vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert). I'm not sure however if you can apply such a separation, the context is missing.

Comment: @dlavila: Because the function may return the root, which is *const* via a return pointer which is *non-const*.  However, the const_cast might not be needed to return linked nodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is not const-correct, it drops a const.  This is why you have the problem of a "required" const cast.  Don't do that:

```
static const Node* findMatchingNode(const Node& root, const SomeFilterData& d);
```

You may point out that you may want to call this function from another function that *does* modify the nodes, and thus wants a non-const result.  As such, that should be a new function with a totally different signature:

```
static Node* findMatchingNode(Node& root, const SomeFilterData& d);
```

You may point out that these have identical bodies, and there's the DRY principle (DRY = Don't Repeat Yourself = Don't have copy-pasted code).  Yes, so just take a shortcut here: const_cast.  I think it's ok in this case, because it's *only* purpose is shared code, and it's clear that it's not violating any const-correctness principles.

```
//This function does not modify anything
static Node* findMatchingNode(Node& root, const SomeFilterData& d) {
    return const_cast<Node*>(findMatchingNode(const_cast<const Node&>(root),d));
}
```

[Loki Asari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14065/loki-astari) suggests adding a third private function `findMatchingNodeCommon()` that both versions of `findMatchingNode()` call. Then you can get away with one less `const_cast`. If you want to go extreme then you can make `findMatchingNodeCommon()` templated and then all `const_cast`s go away.  I think it's not worth the bother, but they're very valid opinions, so worth a mention.

Comment: This is the first non-abusive use of `const_cast` I've ever seen.

Comment: Personally I would add a third private function `findMatchingNodeCommon()` that both versions of `findMatchingNode()` call. Then you can get away with one less `const_cast`. If you want to go extreme then you can make `findMatchingNodeCommon()` templated and then all const_casts go away.

Comment: The second function doesn't meet the OPs requirements - it doesn't provide an explicit guarantee that it doesn't modify the objects in the tree.  (I have no opinion on whether that is a *sensible* requirement, but if you are arguing that it isn't, I think you should do so explicitly.)

Comment: Thanks, I know this technique. _findMatchingNode_ can be turned into template function, so it will deduce constness automatically.

I was just confused with the fact that the function which _guarantees_ input constness only must really tell a user whether he is allowed to modify its output or not

Answer (score 7):

As always, you cannot modify `const` data because it is constant. In particular:

> Even though const_cast may remove constness or volatility from any pointer or reference, using the resulting pointer or reference to write to an object that was declared const or to access an object that was declared volatile invokes undefined behavior.

(from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast))

So if a pointer to the `const` input argument root is a sensible outcome, the return type should be `const` as well. You should be *really* careful with returning pointers anyway: As of now, your function can return a pointer to a temporary!

So better return a [`boost::optional<Node>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) or an [`std::optional<Node>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) (if the latter makes it into C++17 and you use that standard).

If your function only makes sense for a modifiable input `root` (e.g. if the outcome *must* be modifiable *and* the outcome can be the address of `root`), drop the `const` in your declaration. That would also prevent the input `root` from being a temporary.

---

**Most likely the cleanest fix for your potential XY-problem:**

If it fits your use-case (I find it *highly* unlikely that it does not), the most likely even better option would be defining your algorithm on a iteratable data structure like a tree or a list (whatever your `Node` is a node of) and then return an iterator to the matching node, or a past-the-end iterator (with respect to the high-level structure) if no such node exists.

As for the `const`-vs.-non-`const` discussion: With the iterator option you can differentiate between the constness of the high level structure and the reference node you compare stuff with by taking non-`const` iterators over the high level structure and a `const &` argument for the reference input node (where a temporary now would not be a problem).

From what I can see from your question, your function might even be replaceable with [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). Then you would not have this problem in the first place.

Comment: If const is logic const, cast away const is safe.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't stated this clearly, my function is pure function, is doesn't modify anything. Thus there are no pointers to temporary. I got the idea - _pass non-const and output non-const_ either _pass const and output const_.

Though, I wanted to explicitly state with the declaration _const Node& root_ that the function is pure

Comment: I was just confused with the fact that the function which guarantees input constness only must really tell a user whether he is allowed to modify its output or not

Comment: @user2227806 *"Thus there are no pointers to temporary."* You said the function might return a pointer to `root`. Now what happens if I call it like `auto p = findMatchingNode(Node{}, d);`? It might return the address of the temporary parameter, which, even if you return `const`, is a bad thing! Be *very, very* careful with returning pointers and references. Even the C++ standard committee almost got burned!

Comment: @Baum mit Augen, I think it's up to a user to not shoot into his legs. I was meant that the function by itself doesn't perform anything like _"Node node; return &node;"_

Comment: @Baum mit Augen, I understand the dangers. Hopefully, in my case (real case) the Node can't be allocated in scope. And thanks for the answer

Comment: @Baum mit Augen, the unspoken problem behind is that here is no legal way to express constness of the input during the function execution (and only inside the function) without enforcing the output constness.

Comment: @user2227806 First of all, trusting the user to not be stupid is daring at least. Now I feel that the real problem at hand is you handcrafting stuff instead of thinking about what you are actually trying to do in terms of abstract algorithms.  If instead of some function `findMatchingNode` there was a `std::find_if(tree.begin(). tree.end(), isMatching(someNode, d));` we would not need this discussion in the first place.

Comment: @Baum mit Augen, the code in first post is an example only, so std::find_if will never fit. There is no any FilterData. Instead there is a list of int|string|whatever keys. There is no nodes. Instead there are std::vector and std::map

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Standard C++ Foundation](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#return-const-ref-from-const-memfn):

> **What is the relationship between a return-by-reference and a const member function?**
>
> If you want to return a member of your this object by reference from an inspector method, you should return it using reference-to-const (const X& inspect() const) or by value (X inspect() const).

So yeah, you should be returning either by value or a const reference/pointer. You aren't using `this` but the pattern is the same.

Comment: The trick is actually implementing this while keeping DRY in mind.

Comment: @MooingDuck That wasn't the question however thus why this answer doesn't mention any DRYng :) And honestly due to his awareness of const correctness I think he may be able to know how to not repeat himself.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at how the STL does it. There, you have a sequence (delimited by iterators), a predicate that defines a match and a template function that searches. Since it's a template function, it automatically matches the return values const-qualifiers to that of the parameters.

If, for some reason, you don't want to write a template function, you could also add two overloads, because you can overload functions with different const-qualifiers.

Comment: I know this technique. I just wanted to _always_ have _const_ qualifier there to tell everyone clearly that the function doesn't modify anything

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to answer myself, as the original question was not shaped properly. So, my answer can't be treated as a proper.

There is no legit way to express constness of the input (during the function execution) without forcing a user to not modify the output (and without enforcing the output constness).

A way without _const_cast_:

```
static Node* findMatchingNode(Node& root, const SomeFilterData& d);
```

doesn't look like it guarantees the input tree constness.

The original function declaration allows hacks like this, which is also inappropriate:

```
const Node& root = ...
Node* result = findMatchingNode(root, filter);
result->doBadNonConstThings();
```